# How to prevent insertion of invalid dates into a SQLite table?

Tags: database, validation, datetime, sqlite

SQLite tables can't have a column of type date or timestamp. Dates are stored as either text or a number.

That being the case:

- How can I prevent an invalid date like February 31st from being inserted into a table?

I'm know you can validate the date in the application before inserting, but that's not what I'm looking for, since that will not prevent an invalid date from being entered using the SQLite prompt or using some SQLite GUI tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) return NULL when they cannot interpret their date parameter, so you could add a check that this does not happen:

```
CREATE TABLE MyLittleTable (
    MyDate CHECK (date(MyDate) IS NOT NULL)
);
```

However, these functions do not do much checking:

```
> SELECT date('2014-02-31');
2014-02-31
```

To normalize the date, you have to do some computation on it:

```
> SELECT date('2014-02-31', '+0 days');
2014-03-03
```

So you can check that this normalization does not change the value:

```
CREATE TABLE MyLittleTable (
    MyDate CHECK (date(MyDate,'+0 days') IS MyDate)
);
```

(`IS` is needed to handle NULLs correctly.)

Comment: Plus one, and plus an extra one for drawing my attention to the IS operator.

Comment: @FloverOwe Then add another condition to the check expression.

Comment: What about the case that nulls are permitted, but we still want validation when the value is non-null? There are "long" ways to express this, but does anybody know a compact way?

Comment: Nice solution. But is this a good practice to do so, instead of using some other native way of making sure the dates are valid before running the SQL query?

Comment: @sayandcode This question is about an SQLite-only solution. And there is [no such thing as an abstract "good practice"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/242554).